# json_decode returns null - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am sending json object from front-end using ajax call as the following:

```
<button id="btn">click me</button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"/execute",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: 'json',
        data:{
            "test":"hello"
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data.status);
        }
    });


});
</script>
```

and i want to decode this json object in laravel, here is my controller code:

```
public function executeFunction(Request $request){

          if($request->header()['content-type'][0] === 'json')
          {

              Log::info(json_decode($request->getContent(),true));

          }
          return response()->json(["status"=>"success"]);

}
```

json_decode returns null here, what might be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try doing `dd($request->all())` and show what it returns?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: Your ajax call is sent as POST, i'm pretty sure you have to use another method to retrieve your content so use `$request->input('test');`

Comment: @Hooli is right. If it's a POST you should do `$request->post()` to fetch the data

Comment: @user3574492 i am working on 5.4 version of laravel, is this method available on that version?

Comment: @Hooli  even $request->input returns null, why is that?

Comment: @KhaledRimawi Yes it should work. try `dd($request->all())` and show us what you get?

Comment: @user3574492 i tried var_dump instead, this was the output:array(0) {
}, but when i use $request->getContent(), this is the output: string(10) "test=hello"

Comment: @KhaledRimawi Try `dd($request->post())`. It is an old Laravel function and should work.

Comment: i posted a solution to the problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem, the trick is to use JSON.stringify(data) in front end and json_decode will works fine.

Front end code:

```
button id="btn">click me</button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $x = {
       "test":"hello"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:"/execute",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:JSON.stringify($x),
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });


});
</script>
```

Controller code:

```
public function executeFunction(Request $request){

          if($request->header()['content-type'][0] === 'application/json')
          {

              Log::info(json_decode($request->getContent())->test);
          }

    }
```

If you dump the content, this will be the result:

```
object(stdClass)#423 (1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```